# How can I count a page views?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

How can I count page views so that when I go and refresh the page the counter doesn't consider it as new view?

Comment: by refresh the page , you mean pressing f5 ? or revisiting ?

Comment: or both refresh and revisiting

Answer (score 6):

1-declare a session for each user

2- declare application variable for the page visited

and after you start the session

check if page visited like the following:

on the user login page or homepage:

```
Session["pageVisited"] = false;
```

when user visit the page write in the code behind:

```
if(SESSION["pageVisited"] == false)
{
   APPLICATION["Page1Visited"] = Convert.Toint32(APPLICATION["Page1Visited"]) + 1;
   SESSION["pageVisited"] = true;
}
```

Comment: However, if the user visits the page again it wont increase the counter, and it doesnt count as a refresh? so you will only be counting unique views per session.

Answer (score 4):

Use [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) ;)

Comment: Agreed - page views will still be counted on refresh, however you can use page visits to determine unique visitors

Comment: Good approach unless you want to e.g. display number of views within the page.